# Tooltip with jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can  make a tooltip with jquery and css for following HTML? (i mean, this is that when mouse enter on `li a` displaying content class `show_tooltip`)

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">about</a>
    <div class="show_tooltip">
        put returns between paragraphs
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">how</a>
    <div class="show_tooltip">
        for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use a tooltip plugin (there are many) or write some code. Either way, Stack Overflow isn't a "do my work for me" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("li a").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).next().fadeIn();
})
$("li a").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).next().fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: I done it, but not know why tooltip box(same class `.show_tooltip`) there is left when mouse enter on `li a`, i want display each tooltip box top same link that mouse is enter on it. http://jsfiddle.net/AQh6y/3/

Answer (score 0):

why not just do this? :)

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="put returns between paragraphs">about</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="for linebreak add 2 spaces at end">how</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This HTML just is a example, i use from html code in content tooltip.